# Cannot start local SMTP Debugging Server with Python SMTPD module

Tags: python, localhost, mail-server, smtpd

I'm unable to start local SMTP Debugging Server using this line of code:

```
python -m smtpd -c DebuggingServer -n localhost:1025
```

Whenever I run this command on Spyder's command window, I get a syntax error.

Can anyone help me in this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the error message? Which Python version?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

smtpd.DebuggingServer(('localhost', 1025), None)